# Mule inserting empty payload in JMS queue in catch-exception strategy block

Tags: jms, mule

I am simulating a time-out exception (or any other for that sake) when calling external vendor web service. I store the original payload at the start of flow and in catch-exception-strategy, replace the payload with original payload. Payload gets replaced fine, apply XSLT transformer fine, copy the transformed payload to file outbound fine but the strange thing is JMS gets empty message (though message properties are intact). Using `Mule 3.3.1` and `ActiveMQ`. Result is same if Active MQ is replaced by `Sonic`

```
<flow name="orderRequirementsToVendor">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="order.vendor" />
        <set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[message.payload]" />
        <outbound-endpoint address="${vendor.ws.url}" mimeType="text/xml" connector-ref="https.connector" responseTimeout="100">
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
                </cxf:inInterceptors>
                <cxf:outInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
                </cxf:outInterceptors>
            </cxf:proxy-client>
        </outbound-endpoint>
        .
            .
            .

        <choice-exception-strategy>
            <catch-exception-strategy>
                <logger message="In catch exception strategy. Unknown Exception" level="ERROR" /> 
                <logger message="#[exception.causeException]" level="ERROR" />
                <set-payload value="#[flowVars.originalPayload]"/>
                <set-property propertyName="exception" value="#[exception.summaryMessage]"/>                
                <transformer ref="generalErrorTransformer" />   
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="/outbound/vendor/error/ack-before" outputPattern="out_vendor_transformed_ack_error_beforeStatusQueue[function:dateStamp].xml" />
                <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="order.status" /> 
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="/outbound/vendor/error/ack-after" outputPattern="out_vendor_transformed_ack_error_afterStatusQueue[function:dateStamp].xml" />                    
            </catch-exception-strategy>
        </choice-exception-strategy>        
    </flow>
```

Both `ack-before` and `ack-after` has files with correct payload in them but message received in order.status is empty

**EDIT:**
This is the exception in my logs

```
2013-05-29 09:12:33,864 ERROR [orderRequirementsToVendor.stage1.02] exception.AbstractExceptionListener (AbstractExceptionListener.java:299) - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-42999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Read timed out (java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
  java.net.SocketInputStream:-2 (null)
2. Read timed out (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException)
  com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter:617 (null)
3. COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM (org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault)
  org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter:133 (null)
4. COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: What does <transformer ref="generalErrorTransformer" />  do?

Comment: It creates an XML error response, its an XSLT transformer

Comment: What is the type of the empty JMS message sent to `order.status`?

Comment: Can you rephrase question being asked here please, not sure how to know the type of Message. Also, I noticed that on removing `<transformer ref="generalErrorTransformer" />`, order.status queue gets the original payload. There is no problem with transformer though as file outbounds gets correct data.

Comment: Also, please see my edit in the question